# Query that only selects unique data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just can't make a request that will count only unique records.
There is a table: `bbs` with columns:

`to_id` - to whom
`from_id` - from whom

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `bbs` WHERE `to_id`=? OR `from_id`=?
```

You need, for example, this data:

```
from_id  to_id
1          2
2          1
1          3
1          4
1          2
```

That is, for example, we are `1`.
And it should count not `5`, as it currently thinks, but `3`.
You need to select `2` columns, only unique ones.
How to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want a count of records with distinct `from_id`, or distinct `to_id`, or distinct combinations of `from_id` and `to_id`? How does your sample indicate a unique count of only 1?

Comment: @kmoser, Well, that is, the records should be one at a time, but the same ID can be in different columns, and this also needs to be taken into account.

Comment: __That is, for example, we are 1.__ -- Why would that be important in the question?  I think you need to restate your question in clear logical terms.  Without clear logic, it's tough to translate into SQL.

Comment: All 4 pairs are distinct in this set.  How did you manage to decide 1 is the expected answer? Even if we swap pairs such that we have (least(x, y), greatest(x, y)), the answer would still be 3 or 2, depending on whether you wanted to ignore the (1, 2) pairs or just treat them as a single count, followed by (1, 3) and (1, 4).

Comment: What do the `?`s mean in your SQL?  Is this a prepared statement, where we're answering the question for just one pair of `(?, ?)`?  If so, provide an example of parameter values and the corresponding expected result, with a description of the logic you used to determine that result.

Comment: @JonArmstrong, 1 is the id of the current user.
I need to make it count it as one if it occurs in the columns `to_id` or `from_id` at the same time.
In general, I need to count the number of bypasses.
there should be 3 of them.
2, 3 and 4, since the current user is 1
But it turns out all the same 4.
And it is necessary that he selects only unique data, in two columns.

Comment: Sorry.  You're using terms that have no clear logical meaning.  What does `count the number of bypasses` mean?  What is a `bypass`?

Comment: @JonArmstrong, Never mind, it doesn't matter at all, I need to count the amount.
There should be 3 records for the current user ID, how can this be done?

Comment: There are two possible expressions you might be trying to describe.  But neither of them will produce the count of 1.  Assume the columns are `(x, y)`:  1) `SELECT SUM(1 IN (x, y)) FROM tbl;`  This will produce 4, since user = 1 is found in at least one column of each pair. 2) `SELECT SUM(1 = x) FROM tbl;` ... This will produce the result of 3.

Comment: @JonArmstrong, Nothing comes out. if you add one more identical line `from_id = 1` and `to_id = 2`, then the query: `SELECT SUM(1 = x) FROM tbl` will give 4, for place 3. it is necessary that there should be 3. Identical data should not be displayed, even if they are in different columns.

Comment: I suggest starting over, with a new question. None of the above makes sense.

Comment: Counting unique rows (your initial top line question) is trivial. But the rest of your description is not understandable.

Comment: @JonArmstrong, Well, what's incomprehensible? It is necessary to count the records, there should be 3 of them, from the current one that I gave the alignment, you only need to count unique ones that are not the same.

Comment: You've change the expected answer (to 3), which is now understandable.  The original expected answer was (1), which was not understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you mean something like the following.

```sql
select count(distinct(FROM_ID + TO_ID)) as "COUNT"
  from BBS
 where FROM_ID = 1
    or TO_ID = 1
```

That query will return 3, using the sample data in your question.
Refer to [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0410a562f20c6d3a433d2601fed5230).

I'm also guessing that the question marks in the [SQL] query in your question are place holders for a particular ID and you use an example value of 1 (one) in your question. Hence the *where* clause in my [SQL] query, above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id) FROM bbs) AS xx
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using conditional logic for the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN to_id = ? THEN from_id ELSE to_id END) AS `count`
FROM bbs
WHERE ? IN (to_id, from_id);
```

The logic here is quite clear.  There are no strange arithmetic operations on ids -- and this will work on string ids as well.  Nor does it require a subquery.